# Deserialize JSON string (without root)to object VB.NET

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, json.net, json-deserialization

I,

i need to deserialize a sting that contain JSON formatted data but without root element

the data(simplified!) are this

```
[{"ID":"974",
"DataIns":"2022-08-12 14:13:26",
"NumeroFattura":"CTD18473",
"DataFattura":"2022-08-08",
"RagSocMit":"Example1"},

{"ID":"973",
"DataIns":"2022-08-12 13:31:00",
"NumeroFattura":"CTCC10189",
"DataFattura":"2022-08-08",
"RagSocMit":"Example2"},

{"ID":"971",
"DataIns":"2022-08-09 15:30:29",
"NumeroFattura":"C18474",
"DataFattura":"2022-08-08",
"RagSocMit":"Example2"}]
```

and the class for deserializing are this

```
Public Class TestClass
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property DataIns As String
    Public Property NumeroFattura As String
    Public Property DataFattura As String
    Public Property RagSocMit As String
End Class
```

If i try to deserialize with this code

```
    Dim result As String = ""
     Dim ListaFatture As FattureAC2
    ...
     result = reader.ReadToEnd'contain the sting json from a WS
    ListaFatture = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IEnumerable(Of FattureAC2))(result)
```

ListaFatture are equal to NOTHING

Someone can help me?

Tnx

Salvo

Comment: Might be a copy paste error, you're deserialising to IEnumerable(Of FattureAC2) but your class is Public Class TestClass.  Does  IEnumerable(Of TestClass) make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

you can not deserialize as IEnumerable, you have to select what do you need  an array or list for example

```
Dim ListaFatture As List (Of TestClass)
ListaFatture = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of TestClass))(result)
```

Comment: Tnx. I think that i need a list of tipe but at 23.45 o clock is an hard life!!!